# expo audio not accepting array as source parameter

Tags: android, react-native, expo

am trying to make an offline playlist app with react native, am using expo audio https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/ and this example project https://expo.io/@documentation/playlist-example, the documentation says you can give source and intialstatus and then load the audio file

```
const {sound, status} = await Audio
      .Sound
      .createAsync(source, initialStatus);
```

you can upload a file from the internet by using

```
const source = { uri: online-link};
```

or you can upload an audio file from the project's directory by typing

```
const source = require('file-location');
```

so i put the links in an array, gave an index!

```
const source = { uri: PlayList[this.index].uri};
```

this didn't work an so did the other methode!! even though when i console log PlayList[this.index].uri it gives correct path !!

the error log :

```
Remote debugger is in a background tab which may cause apps to perform slowly. Fix this by foregrounding the tab (or opening it in a separate window).
- node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:166:14 in _captureConsoleStackTrace
- node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:41:24 in serializeLogDataAsync$
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals

[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Audio mode attempted to be set without the required keys: ["staysActiveInBackground"]]
- node_modules/expo-av/build/Audio.js:30:14 in setAudioModeAsync$
- node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:39 in tryCatch
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals

[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Cannot load an AV asset from a null playback source]
- node_modules/expo-av/build/AV.js:115:14 in getNativeSourceAndFullInitialStatusForLoadAsync$
- node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:39 in tryCatch
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Comment: NOTE : the app works when i do both methods without an array,

Comment: can you post expo  snack with issue?

Comment: sorry i took long to reply here is the link :  https://snack.expo.io/@noob-dev/5b84d0

Comment: if anyone is having the same problem, you just have to add a require function to the array instead of just writing the path, good luck !

Comment: Check this (add require with expo 34) : https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/unnamed-snack